# Angular localhost crashing

Tags: angular, crash, localhost

I start the localhost with `ng serve` but after some time the localhost server crashes with this error:

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/myName/Desktop/Codice/Sviluppo App Web/Kontaki/.angular/cache/16.2.10/angular-webpack/b673c28bd39d300653e038964716ebbb78260348/8.pack'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/myName/Desktop/Codice/Sviluppo App Web/Kontaki/.angular/cache/16.2.10/angular-webpack/b673c28bd39d300653e038964716ebbb78260348/8.pack'
}
```

Node.js v18.17.0

I always have to restart it... Anyone knows why? Maybe some conflicts?

I tried to reinstall Angular and NPM but nothing works, after 5-10 minutes it crashes...

If you need any folder of the project configuration, I'll post it, I don't know what could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to some issues at angular cache directory.
Try to remove it and start again:

```
rm -rf .angular/cache
ng serve
```

Comment: Thank you, right now it seems to work, it is still running after the codes you suggested me.